# problemas con edición de post

Tags: reactjs

en una app que tiene el crud en desarrollo, pero cada vez que actualizo un post este pasa perfectamente en los inputs de la mismo formulario de edicion, sin embargo cuando quiero editar otro post dentro de la lista al momento que se abre el formulario de edicion este sigue con los datos del ultimo post editado y no el post que se desea editar en si. Aun no logro ver que podria estar pasando dentro de la app. La app esta hecha de tal manera que toda la data y acciones estan centralizadas al componente padre App.js y este por medio de props se pasan los distintos datos a los otros componentes.

Adjunto git para que se pueda entender de mejor manera: https://github.com/ricardosikic/CRUD-App

Adjunto codigo de App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {

state = {
  posts: [],
  singlePost: {},
  isOpen: false
}

addNewPost = (post) => {
  const newData = post
  this.setState({
    posts: this.state.posts.concat(newData)
  })
}

openModal = (post) => {
  this.setState({
    isOpen: true
    // singlePost: post
  })
}

closeModal = (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: false
    })
  }, 1000);
  }

updatePost = (rePost) => {
  console.log('actualizado!', rePost);
  const newData = [...this.state.posts, rePost]
  this.setState({
    posts: this.state.posts.concat(rePost)
  })
}



render(){
  return(
    <Fragment>

    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-6">
          <Form addNew={e => this.addNewPost(e)} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-6">
          <List posts={this.state.posts} openModal={e => this.openModal(e)} />
          <Edit active={this.state.isOpen} update={e => this.updatePost(e)} closeModal={e => this.closeModal(e)}  post={this.state.singlePost}/>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
   </Fragment>
 );

  }
}

export default App;
```

**edit form component:**

```
export class Edit extends React.Component {

state = {
    postEdit: {}
}

handleData = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const updatedData = { [name]: value }
    const newData = {...this.state.postEdit, ...updatedData}
    this.setState({
        postEdit: newData
    })
    console.log('post edited ', this.state.postEdit)
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.update()
}

render() {
    console.log('nombre ', this.props.post.nombre)
    console.log('apellido ', this.props.post.apellido)
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <div className={this.props.active ? 'open' : 'close'}>
                <h3>Actualiza usuario</h3>
                <form className="mt-3" onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.post.nombre} onChange={e => this.handleData(e)} name='nombre' className="form-control"  placeholder="Nombre" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.post.apellido} onChange={e => this.handleData(e)} name='apellido' className="form-control" placeholder="Apellido" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={e => this.props.closeModal(e)}>Actualizar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
 }
}
```

Comment: Check `Edit` component, is receiving data from props on mounting so forms will be fulfilled if you don't clear fields after submission.

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia, i try to clear the fields after submission in the updatePost function with no success

Comment: If you don't want to save last user inputs, then use `Edit` component internal state to handle form, and then on submit pass full form to parent to handle it. Then you can easy clear local state from Edit component instead of loading those from props.

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia i have edited  the post and add the edit component with it own state to handle data from that form inputs, then call the update function after submitted the post updated. maybe im not cleaning the fields there XD

Comment: Look at the values in those inputs, are received from props